# htaccess url rewrite rule for html extensions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying make a rule using htaccess on for urls having .html extension but having problem

I want when someone tries to access any html file like below request in browser
https://{domain.com}/abc/file.html

Its should be served from below path
https://{domain.com}/xyz/{domain.com}/abc/file.html

domain.com is pointed to my server only and it is dynamic means can be changed for different vendors.

I want to rewrite rule not redirect rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds pretty straight forward, you need to implement a rewrite rule for that:

This would be a general approach which internally rewrites *all* requests:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ /xyz/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,END]
```

Here an alternative which only rewrites requests to paths ending with ".html" which you seem to suggest in your question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^ /xyz/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).